# Javascript - create unique file per user

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am developing an application that allows users to embed a short code on their website and my software will capture all their form data and place it in our database.

I need to generate a unique JS file for each user and add some generic code to each file with dynamic variables that are stored in a mysql database.

For Example:

- main.js - this file contains the generic code
- userid.js - this file is generated when a user creates an account and this file takes all the content from main.js, replaced the dynamic variables with data from the database and displays generic javascript code.

I have been playing with node.js File system and it seems like that is the way to go. Can anyone help me understand how the above can be accomplished? I am confused as to how would I go about updated the code in userid.js whenever I updated main.js?

Thanks

Comment: have you considered storing the js in the database instead ... js is simply a string

Comment: The reason it has to be in a file is because the user will embed that file into their contact page like:

<script src="domain.com/121323.js"></script>

Comment: right, and this file exists on your server?

Comment: that is correct.

Comment: It may help you to know that URL's don't have to target actual files

Comment: Interesting. So you are saying that its possible to have a dynamic file name like {userid}.js which loads up generic code+dynamic variables from database or another file?

Comment: yes, though maybe not that simple. Usually one would have a route like `/user/{here is the unique identifier}.js`

Comment: and what about the javescript that is suppose to show in this file with dynamic variables, where does it come from? or is this one file like main.js which can be accesses through unique identifiers?

Comment: to be fair, you've shown no code, so I can't really speculate how an unwritten system could possibly work

Comment: All the code I have written is for capturing form data not for a js file name to be changed dynamically. Can you point me to some information that will help me accomplish /user/{here is the unique identifier}.js?

Comment: well then, you have some learning and coding to do

Comment: I agree :). I am new to javascript. Any pointers would be helpful

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_pathname?

Comment: not sure what that is for ... look into something like node express - plenty of tutorials around for that

Comment: Hey, this really helped man. express js is a good start. I am playing with routing which is how I think this can be accomplished. thanks again

Comment: This problem is already solved within 10 mins of you pointing me to express js. Routing my man, routing. Thank You

Comment: expressjs does make life very easy :p

Comment: There's no reason to put a physical file on disk.  Just use a template system such as jade, ejs or handlebars and render a script file where objects in the template are replaced with data from your database on behalf of the current user.  This will customize the script file per user.  It's the same way that user-specific data is rendered into an HTML file in most web sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this through using Node.js and Express.js. Basically, I built a route that can contain user id. Then, I used pug to display that javascript data in this dynamic url.

Answer (score 0):

Have your customer's html web-form call your javascript file (function) in order to make a server call, (i.e., an ajax call) to your server:

```
<form name="myForm">
<input name="userName">
<button onclick="createFileName_SendToServer()" type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<!-- language: lang-js -->
<script>
function createFileName_SendToServer(){
  // 1: Get user name from the web form
    var userName = document.myForm.userName.value;
    // clearly this can be used for all form fields
  // 2: Use the userName as the name of the new file
    var userIdFileName = userName + ".js";
  // 3: send this info to your server script 
    // make an AJAX call, add additional args for other form data
    var trueOrFalse = ajaxToYourServer(userIdFileName);
}
</script>
```

The JS function sends (via AJAX) your server script the name of the userIDFileName (along with any other form data). Your server script can then query the database, create the file (from the provided file handle), navigate the file system and save the file.

Comment: This does not answer my question. I was in need of unique userid.js filename. This was solved by using express js routing for my app and sendFile function. Thanks